# Add a fixed amount to formula range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with a long INDEX/MATCH with 30 tables of data. I have to repeat the formula 30 times.

First range is F10:F24. Second range is F29:F43 and so on therefore ranges 2~30 are 19 rows down the previous one. Dragging the cell to the right is not going to work in this case, so is there any other way to avoid editing 30 long formulas?

Edit:

Here are two partial samples for first and second column:

=INDEX(Fixtures!$F$10:$F$24,MATCH(T!$C$4,Fixtures!$E$10:$E$24,0),1)
=INDEX(Fixtures!$F$29:$F$43,MATCH(T!$C$4,Fixtures!$E$29:$E$43,0),1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two INDEXes with some Math to set the ranges:

```
INDEX($F:$F,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*19+10):INDEX($F:$F,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*19+24)
```

This will now set the the ranges F10:F24,F29:F43,... as it is dragged to the right.

In you formula:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(Fixtures!$F:$F,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*19+10):INDEX(Fixtures!$F:$F,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*19+24),MATCH(T!$C$4,INDEX(Fixtures!$E:$E,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*19+10):INDEX(Fixtures!$E:$E,(COLUMN(A1)-1)*19+24),0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question to provide more info. Please tell me how to apply your logic to it.